# Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0.0.RELEASE:Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway, hystrix

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=debug
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://BIZSERVICE-DEMO
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/demo/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].name=StripPrefix
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].args.parts=1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1].name=Hystrix
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1].args.name=fallbackcmd
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1].args.fallbackUri=forward:/fallback
hystrix.command.fallbackcmd.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

When I run gateway service,visit http://.../demo/123,the console reports:

> 2018-08-02 14:50:49.454 [reactor-http-nio-2] ERROR ipf.filter.ExceptionHandler - {timestamp=Thu Aug 02 14:50:49 CST 2018,
> path=/demo/demo/1, status=500, error=Internal Server Error,
> message=Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix,
> trace=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
> GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix
> at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.lambda$loadGatewayFilters$3(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:142)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
> at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
> at

What is the cause of it, and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: It looks like you have not provided enough details in order for someone to help you. Can you provide more details with what plugins your using, what you've tried before and about your setup.

Comment: StripPrefix file is valid，but Hystrix file is avaliabled，report:Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix . I debug the program in the source:

public class RouteDefinitionRouteLocator,find hystrix filter don't exsits in  gatewayFilterFactories:SetPath、RequestHeaderToRequestUri、ModifyResponseBody、RemoveRequestHeader、RedirectTo、、ModifyRequestBody、SetResponseHeader、SecureHeaders、AddRequestParameter、AddResponseHeader、PreserveHostHeader、RewritePath、SetStatus、SetRequestHeader、PrefixPath、Retry、AddRequestHeader、RemoveResponseHeader、SaveSession、、StripPrefix

Comment: private List<GatewayFilter> loadGatewayFilters(String id, List<FilterDefinition> filterDefinitions) {
        List filters = (List)filterDefinitions.stream().map((definition) -> {
            GatewayFilterFactory factory = (GatewayFilterFactory)this.gatewayFilterFactories.get(definition.getName());
            if(factory == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name " + definition.getName());
            }



debug:info: definition:"FilterDefinition{name='Hystrix',args={fallbackUri=forward:/fallback,name=fallbackcmd}}"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,you should use this dependency
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>`

not this one
`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>`